# Transferring Microsoft Office 2010 to a new computer

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, transfer

I recently bought a new computer, and would like to transfer Microsoft Office (Home and Student) 2010 to my new computer. I Googled it, but couldn't find anything useful (except for apologies that this could not be done without an activation code).
My old computer has Windows 7 Starter, my new computer has Windows 8.1 (if that matters).
I still have the <s>activation code</s> product key, and I also have Office Home and Student installed on two other computers, so I can't use the '3-for-1' deal.

How can I transfer Office to my new computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called Microsoft (actually, just requested a callback from the AnswerDesk [here](http://support.microsoft.com/)), and had the issue resolved in 35 minutes.

We just installed Office on my new computer, and put in the product key, and it now works!

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm understanding your question wrong, you can simply install office on your new PC. The home and student version can be installed on 3 different PC's at any one time. I'm assuming your activation code is what is also called a product key, which is a series of 25 characters in the following format:

```
XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
```

If you're missing the installation medium, or your PC doesn't have an optical drive, you can download office from [here](https://www7.downloadoffice2010.microsoft.com/usa/registerkey.aspx?culture=EN-US&ref=backup&country_id=US).

Licence information for Office 2010 can be found [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-software-license-terms-for-microsoft-office-2010-HA101817777.aspx).

The links provided are for customers in the US, so you might need to change country if you're located somewhere else.

Hope this helps.

Comment: All three licenses are currently in use. Yes, I probably meant the product key, :)

Comment: I am in the US.

Comment: If all 3 licences are in use, simply uninstall from your Win7 starter PC before installing on your new PC. According to some sources, you might need to go through the phone activation process.

Comment: That's [what I thought](http://superuser.com/questions/829739/transferring-microsoft-office-2010-to-a-new-computer/829750?noredirect=1#comment1089553_829739), but I'd rather be sure.....

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but [I figured it out with help from Microsoft](http://superuser.com/a/830129/333963). Thanks again!